# I want to convert varchar date column to date to get between date results

Tags: sql-server, select

I want to get the resulting output between two dates which are stored in my SQL table as `varchar(50)` in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Actually, I don't know what the problem is in my query mentioned below but it's throwing this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My SQL select query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(bno), 
    name, cdate, ctime, 
    CAST(ISNULL(disc, '0') AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS 'Discount', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ptype = 'Cash' THEN CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) END) AS 'Cash', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ptype = 'Online' THEN CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) END) AS 'Online', 
    CAST(ISNULL(paid, '0') AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS 'GT' 
FROM
    Sales 
WHERE 
    bno != '0' 
    AND CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(50), cdate, 105)) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(50), '01-09-2020', 105)) 
                                                            AND CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(50), '13-09-2020', 105)) 
GROUP BY
    bno, name, cdate, ctime, disc, paid
```

Please let me know if any corrections are required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The real quesy is why are you storing dates as a `varchar` in the first place?

Comment: Also white space and line breaks are important when writing any language, including SQL. Take the time to format your code.

Comment: Finally, looks like you are using both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` here. This eaitber means the former is redundant, or the latter is incomplete; you never need both in the same statement.

Comment: You're just not learning from your previous questions. Date literals do not need to be converted with a style if you use an unambiguous format. Learn to do **just that!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my opinion you have multiple problems.

1. Your cdate field have a format yyyy-mm-dd then your format convert are not exact. Tru to use try_cast
2. When you use a 'case instruction' you must use 'else' clause too
3. Your "group by" must use the same fieds/fields calculate of your select clause
4. Distinct are always redundant in group by
5. Use try_cast for the cases when your data are not correct for the type waiting
6. You group by paid in GT but you use paid in sum, not really logic
7. I suspect your ctime should be used in your clause where / between (cdate + ctime is your date possibly)

Try something like this :

```
select bno, name, cdate, ctime,
TRY_CAST ( isnull(disc, '0') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Discount', 
sum(case when ptype = 'Cash' then TRY_CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18,2)) else null end) as 'Cash', 
sum(case when ptype = 'Online' then TRY_CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18,2)) else null end) as 'Online', 
sum(TRY_CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'GT'
from Sales 
where bno!='0' and 
Try_cast(cdate as date) between '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-13'
group by bno, name, cdate, ctime, TRY_CAST ( isnull(disc, '0') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

If you want find all your problems in you datas you can do it:

```
select bno, name, cdate, ctime, ptype, paid 
from Sales 
where bno!='0' and 
(
Try_cast( cdate as date) is null and cdate<>'' or
case when ptype = 'Cash' then TRY_CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18,2)) else null end is null and ptype = 'Cash' and paid<>'' or
case when ptype = 'Online' then TRY_CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18,2)) else null end is null and ptype = 'Online' and paid<>'' or
TRY_CAST ( isnull(disc, '0') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) is null and disc<>'' or
TRY_CAST ( isnull(paid, '0') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) is null and paid<>'' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to apply formatting on the between filters. keep the same format on the table field and the query would be something like below:

```
select
   (bno),
   name,
   cdate,
   ctime,
   CAST(isnull(disc, '0') AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) as 'Discount',
   sum(   case
              when ptype = 'Cash' then
                  CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
          end
      ) as 'Cash',
   sum(   case
              when ptype = 'Online' then
                  CAST(paid AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
          end
      ) as 'Online',
  CAST(IsNULL(paid, '0') AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) as 'GT' from Sales where bno != '0'
  AND convert(date,cdate)
  BETWEEN '01-09-2020' AND '13-09-2020'
  group by bno,name,cdate,ctime,disc,paid
```

Hope this helps.The key point is this statement (SELECT CONVERT(date,'01-09-2020')) will output by default in to this date format (2020-01-09), So if you keep the same format in your table field you can apply the filtering without doing much effort.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is still redundant here, if the OPs `GROUP BY` is correct. It should be noted, as well, that the query won't be SARgable, so won't make use of any indexes; meaning it could be very slow with large datasets

Comment: The opposite problem of OP's formatting. So much white space and linebreaking but **still** difficult to read. And there is no need to cast date literals when they use a format that is unambiguous. Here it's done without a style and can still fail.

Comment: Thanks @SMor I have updated the query and only concentrated in the Date conversion issue.

Please run a quick test just with select (all your existing fields) and just apply below as the filters in the where clause.

convert(date,cdate) BETWEEN '01-09-2020' AND '13-09-2020'
This will give you an idea whether the date issue has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I have updated the Query and removed "DISTINCT" and there is no use with Grouping , I have just focused on the date conversion issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error you are seeing is that you're applying the `style` parameter of the [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to the conversion to `varchar`, not the conversion to `date`. You need to change:

```
AND CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(50), cdate, 105)) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(50), '01-09-2020', 105)) 
                                                        AND CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(50), '13-09-2020', 105))
```

to:

```
AND CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(50), cdate), 105) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(50), '01-09-2020'), 105)
                                                        AND CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(50), '13-09-2020'), 105)
```

Note that style 105 is `dd-mm-yyyy`, which you are using correctly in the `BETWEEN` part of the expression, but you mention that the dates in your table are stored in `yyyy-mm-dd` form, in which case you should convert them using style 23.